# MS-Access - you tried to execute a query Syntax error in JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help, I can't see what I did wrong. But I have 2 group by's

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SalesmanTable.SalesNum,
    (SalesmanTable.SalesFName & ' ' & SalesmanTable.SalesLName),
    BusinessInfo.BusinessNum,
    BusinessInfo.BusinessName,
    BusinessInfo.OwnerName 
FROM
    ((SalesmanTable 
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderInfo ON SalesmanTable.[SalesNum] = OrderInfo.[SalesNum]) 
LEFT JOIN 
    BusinessInfo ON OrderInfo.[BusinessNum] = BusinessInfo.[BusinessNum] 
WHERE
    OrderInfo.Paid = FALSE 
GROUP BY 
    SalesmanTable.SalesNum, BusinessInfo.BusinessNum 
GROUP BY 
    SalesmanTable.SalesNum, 
    (SalesmanTable.SalesFName & ' ' & SalesmanTable.SalesLName), 
    BusinessInfo.BusinessNum, BusinessInfo.BusinessName, BusinessInfo.OwnerName;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your `FROM` clause:

```
FROM ((SalesmanTable LEFT JOIN
       OrderInfo
       ON SalesmanTable.[SalesNum] = OrderInfo.[SalesNum]
      ) LEFT JOIN
      BusinessInfo
      ON OrderInfo.[BusinessNum] = BusinessInfo.[BusinessNum]
```

The parentheses do not balance.  So:

```
FROM (SalesmanTable LEFT JOIN
      OrderInfo
      ON SalesmanTable.[SalesNum] = OrderInfo.[SalesNum]
     ) LEFT JOIN
     BusinessInfo
     ON OrderInfo.[BusinessNum] = BusinessInfo.[BusinessNum]
```